# How to sort this ArrayList using collection.sort that uses object?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

```
import java.util.*;
class student
{
    int roll;
    int marks;
    student(int roll, int marks)
    {
        this.roll=roll;
        this.marks=marks;
    }
}

public class eList4
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scann=new Scanner(System.in);
List <student> mylist= new ArrayList<student>();
int n=scann.nextInt();
while((n--)>0)
{
    System.out.println(n+" enter student details:");
    int roll=scann.nextInt();
    int marks=scann.nextInt();
    student temp=new student(roll, marks);
    mylist.add(temp);
}

Collections.sort(mylist, new Comparator<student>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(student a, student b) {
        int k=b.roll;
        int kk=a.roll;
        if(b.roll>a.roll)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
});
System.out.println(mylist);
Iterator itr = mylist.iterator();
i=0;
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    student temp=itr.next();

    System.out.println(temp.roll +"  "+temp.marks);

}   

}

}
```

well this is giving me the same result, there's no sorting at all.
how do I sort on the basis of roll no.s?
This is giving the same result.
well this is giving me the same result, there's no sorting at all.
how do I sort on the basis of roll no.s?
This is giving the same result.

Comment: Your `compare` method never returns -1.

Comment: so what should I do to make this work correctly?

Comment: return b.roll<a.roll? -1 : b.roll>a.roll? 1 : 0; in your compare method

Comment: that didn't work @Unknown

Comment: What did not work? It should work

Comment: You yourself check once. It really did not.

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing "roll" property of student class properly, use below code:

```
        @Override
        public int compare(student a, student b) {
            return ((Integer)a.roll).compareTo(((Integer)b.roll));
        }
```

We can not compare primitive data type using compareTo() method, so cast "roll" property to Integer wrapper class. And your compare method is ready to compare.

Hope this works!

Comment: Good to know. Cheers!